# Desktop comes very late after login; IPv6?

Tags: boot, xorg, lightdm

I'm struggling with a very slow desktop appearing after login screen, after boot or after restarting `lightdm`.

Here is the tail of `dmesg`:

```
[   23.011522] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eno1: link becomes ready
[ 3685.276857] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[ 3685.303970] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[ 3685.327473] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/O MODULE].
[ 3685.344112] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.
[ 3685.433962] raid6: sse2x1   gen()  7501 MB/s
[ 3685.501958] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6837 MB/s
[ 3685.569963] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 12295 MB/s
[ 3685.637957] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9197 MB/s
[ 3685.705957] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15418 MB/s
[ 3685.773960] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 11172 MB/s
[ 3685.773961] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 15418 MB/s
[ 3685.773962] raid6: .... xor() 11172 MB/s, rmw enabled
[ 3685.773963] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
[ 3685.802941] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
[ 3685.841958]    avx       : 24488.000 MB/sec
[ 3685.875216] Btrfs loaded
[ 9925.165391] show_signal_msg: 24 callbacks suppressed
[ 9925.165397] Watchdog[7914]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000029fd366 sp 00007f9b336a84d0 error 6 in Messenger[400000+43ea000]
[ 9936.445878] Watchdog[9216]: segfault at 0 ip 00000000029fd366 sp 00007fc333ae84d0 error 6 in Messenger[400000+43ea000]
[14286.598335] perf interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[70410.480861] QXcbEventReader[14228]: segfault at 7f88e77fe349 ip 00007f88e77fe349 sp 00007f88e6de0ee0 error 14
[81948.322475] perf interrupt took too long (5013 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

I tried fixing it by adding the following to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

but it still appears in my dmesg...

Comment: @Rinzwind I wasn't even aware this computer had wifi. But fair enough, I've set "IPv6 Method: Ignore" for my ethernet. At least for the next years, that shouldn't be of any problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, this fixed the issue

Comment: You can find information here https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: @FooBar make an answer then and accept it ;-)